# Отправка формы на чистом javascript при помощи phpmailer

Tags: javascript, phpmailer

Есть лендинг, нужно сделать отправку формы на чистом javascript.
Письмо отправляется, но оно приходит пустое. На jquery все работает.

```
const forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
const message = {
    loading: 'img/form/spinner.svg',
    success: 'Спасибо! Скоро мы с вами свяжемся',
    failure: 'Что-то пошло не так...'
};

forms.forEach(item => {
    postData(item);
});

function postData(form) {
    form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        let statusMessage = document.createElement('img');
        statusMessage.src = message.loading;
        statusMessage.style.cssText = `
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
        `;
        form.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', statusMessage);
    
        const formData = new FormData(form);

        const object = {};
        formData.forEach(function(value, key){
            object[key] = value;
        });

        fetch('mailer/smart.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(object)
        }).then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            showThanksModal(message.success);
            statusMessage.remove();
        }).catch(() => {
            showThanksModal(message.failure);
        }).finally(() => {
            form.reset();
        });
    });
}

function showThanksModal(message) {
  const prevModalDialog = document.querySelector('.modal__dialog');

  prevModalDialog.classList.add('hide');
  openModal();

  const thanksModal = document.createElement('div');
  thanksModal.classList.add('modal__dialog');
  thanksModal.innerHTML = `
      <div class="modal__content">
          <div class="modal__close" data-close>×</div>
          <div class="modal__title">${message}</div>
      </div>
  `;
  document.querySelector('.modal').append(thanksModal);
  setTimeout(() => {
      thanksModal.remove();
      prevModalDialog.classList.add('show');
      prevModalDialog.classList.remove('hide');
      closeModal();
  }, 4000);
```

}

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: application/json');


$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$textarea = $_POST['textarea'];

require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';

// $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'mail@gmail.com';                 // Наш логин
$mail->Password = 'gmail';                           // Наш пароль от ящика
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to
 
$mail->setFrom('mail@gmail.com', 'Сайт');   // От кого письмо 
$mail->addAddress('mail@yandex.ru');     // Add a recipient
//$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
//$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
//$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');
//$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
//$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Данные';
$mail->Body    = '
        Пользователь оставил данные <br> <br>
    Имя: ' . $name . ' <br><br>
    Номер телефона: ' . $phone . '<br><br>
    E-mail: ' . $email . '<br><br>
    Cообщение: ' .$textarea . '';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}

?>
```

[image: Результат]

**Решение**
Записать данный код в начале php файла

```
$_POST = json_decode( file_get_contents("php://input"), true );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно посмотреть что приходит в `$_POST`, так как Вы отправляете данные как JSON строку, если я не ошибаюсь, используя `JSON.stringify()`, то Вам нужно же потом преобразовать эти данные так чтобы с ними можно было работать дальше на PHP обратно в массив/объект. Вы же обращаетесь к элементам массива, например `$_POST['name']`, но на данный момент это строка. Используйте [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php) для этого. Таким образом Вы можете преобразовать данные в массив или объект, как Вам удобнее и далее работать с оным.

Comment: А могу я  изменить javascript файл, не меняя php?

Comment: @ПавелРыбакин в `fetch` `body` должен быть строкой, c `XMLHttpRequest` тоже самое

Comment: Все таки получилось через json_decode(), просто не знал что куда записывать. в итоге в начало php файла нужно было написать.